# Julia, how to completely remove it from your system? (linux)

Tags: linux, apt, package-management

how to uninstall Julia completely in linux? `sudo apt uninstall julia` doesn't seem to work. I want to remove everything julia related

Comment: what about `apt purge julia`

Comment: "_`sudo apt uninstall julia` doesn't seem to work_" - why not? What happens? Error messages?

Comment: How did you install it? What distro is this?

Answer (score 1):

The command is

```
sudo apt remove julia
```

not

```
sudo apt uninstall julia
```

A variant, which also removes configuration files, is

```
sudo apt purge julia
```

Answer (score -3):

The answer is just to remove the `~/.julia` directory.

https://julialang.org/downloads/platform/#uninstallation__3

Comment: That doesn't uninstall julia, unless that's how you installed it in the first place